# Keep all alpha and numeric characters and turn white space into -

Tags: javascript, regex

What im trying to do is:
Take a string

1. remove anything that is not alpha and numeric characters.
2. Im also trying to turn any white space into a -, (multiple white space will become a single -)
3. covert all into lower case

The reason for this is to generate a friendly URL from a user input

This is all i have so far

```
var str = "This is    a really bad Url _, *7% !";
result1 = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
alert(result1);
```

Comment: The desired output in that case is `"this-is-a-really-bad-url-7-"` ?

Comment: Allright, then you have plenty of answers to choose from ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could do the trick

```
var str = "This is    a really bad Url _, *7% !";
result1 = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, '') // Remove non alphanum except whitespace
             .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '')      // Remove leading and trailing whitespace
             .replace(/\s+/g, '-')          // Replace (multiple) whitespaces with a dash
             .toLowerCase();
alert(result1);
```

Result :

```
this-is-a-really-bad-url-7
```

Comment: I didn't bother as the input is probably a title, but you're right, it's much safer. Edited !

Comment: str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, '') is going to replace spaces before it gets to .replace(/\s+/g, '-')

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var output=input.replace(/[^A-Za-z\d\s]+/g,"").replace(/\s+/g," ").toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just expand on what you already got: first convert whitespaces to hyphen, then replace everything except letters, digits and hyphens with an empty string - and finally convert to lower case:

```
var str = "This is    a really bad Url _, *7% !";
result1 = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d-]/g, '').toLowerCase();
alert(result1);
```

You also need to think what you want to do about initial hyphens ('-') in the string.  My code above will keep them.  If you want them removed as well, then change the second line to

```
result1 = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z\d\s]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: wow this was fast, Thank you.
what would i do to also remove the underscore?

Comment: this would not replace `_`

Comment: @Anirudh fine, you can substitute `\w` with `A-Za-z` - I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "This is    a really bad Url _, *7% !";
result1 = str
            .replace(/[^A-Za-z\d\s]+/g, "")  //delete all non alphanumeric characters, don't touch the spaces
            .replace(/\s+/g, '-')             //change the spaces for -
            .toLowerCase();                   //lowercase

alert(result1);
```

Comment: thats exactly similar to my solution..except `alet`...:P

Comment: True, I think I'll just delete mine, you answered first

Answer (score 0):

I looked at all these and some missed some things.

```
var stripped = string.toLowerCase() // first lowercase for it to be easier
            .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '') // THEN leading and trailing whitespace. We do not want "hello-world-"
            .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // THEN replace spaces with -
            .replace(/[^a-z0-9-\s]/g, '');// Lastly
```

Comment: What I am using on a project: var stripped = string.toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^a-z0-9-_\s]/g, '');